# Apache Lucene 6.2 StandardAnalyzer version

Tags: java, lucene

I'm new to Apache Lucene. I'm using currently the latest version: 6.2.1

Based on their official documentation : http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html

```
 Version matchVersion = Version.LUCENE_6_2_1;
 Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(matchVersion);
```

doesn't work. It tells me there is no StandardAnalyzer constructor that receives a Version parameter;

I did something like this

```
 Version matchVersion = Version.LUCENE_6_2_1;
 Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
 analyzer.setVersion(matchVersion);
```

Is this the correct way to do and the documentation is older? Or I need to add some more extra libraries besides lucene-core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `Version` argument was removed in version 5.0. Setting it using `setVersion` would be correct. However, it should be noted that setting the version won't actually do anything. `StandardAnalyzer` doesn't use it.

If you want to use the old `StandardAnalyzer` logic (used in version 3.1 and before), you should use [`ClassicAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/ClassicAnalyzer.html) instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I see . Are there any use cases for Version then? What happen when in the future I'll upgrade to lucene 6.3 for example?

Comment: Oh, there are still analyzers that do use it, among other things. StandardAnalyzer just doesn't. How it operates hasn't really changed significantly for quite some time.